# surprising compilation error getting the array class of a class

Tags: java, generics, reflection

Lately I've been doing a lot with reflection and implemented this little utility method. I was surprised to find that the first version does not compile, but the latter does.

Does not compile:

```
 public static <T> Class<T[]> getArrayClassOfType(Class<T> componentType) {
     return Array.newInstance(componentType, 0).getClass();
 }
```

Compiles and works just fine:

```
 public static <T> Class<T[]> getArrayClassOfType(Class<T> componentType) {
     Class c = Array.newInstance(componentType, 0).getClass();
     return c;
 }
```

Two questions: what's wrong with it? is there a better way of doing this?

Here's the compilation error from the first:

```
TypeUtils.java:[12,60] incompatible types: java.lang.Class<capture#1 of ? extends java.lang.Object> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<T[]>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The return type of `getClass()` is `Class<?>`.

In your example, you are assigning `Class<?>` to `Class<T[]>` (in the return statement), which is wrong, you need a cast.

This will compile fine:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") // added to suppress compiler warning
public static <T> Class<T[]> getArrayClassOfType(Class<T> componentType)
{
    return (Class<T[]>) Array.newInstance(componentType, 0).getClass();
}
```

With your second example, you use raw type `Class`, which works OK - casting raw type seems to be implicit. However, you will get a compiler warning, since this is a discouraged technique.

If you properly parametrize it as `Class<?>`, you will need the cast too.

Comment: Ah. I tried that, but intellij was still upset (red underline about inconvertible types) even with the suppress warnings. Seems I've found a bug.

Comment: If you have the cast, it should be OK. Maybe you have the IDE configured to treat this kind of warning as error? I know you can do that in Eclipse.

Comment: Hm, I looked for ways to adjust the level on this kind of error but didn't find it. I also see jetbrains has fixed a case (here http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-105846) like this as a bug before, so I'll submit it.